# How can i make central raised tabbar item?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbaritem

At first I want to say that i am new in iPhone application development.I want to make a tabbaritem when i will select a item of the tabbar then it should be look like that

[image]

Many Thanks In Advance.

Comment: uitabbar does not provide support for what you're trying to achieve. This can only be done using a set of custom views.

Comment: can u send me how can i custom that view?

Comment: check this out http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

Comment: or this https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController

Comment: you can update those to suit your needs, functionality is already in place, it just needs some UI redesign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to create custom tab bar by Sub classing `UITabBarController`.

TabBarController.h file :

```
@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController<UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{
    UITabBarController *tabController;

    UIImageView *img1;
    UIImageView *img2;
    UIImageView *img3;
    UIImageView *img4;
}
```

.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{       
    [self loadTabView];
    //[self viewWillAppear:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];        
}

- (void) loadTabView 
{
    tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabController.delegate = self;
    tabController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //set offset for tabbar items images. 
    int topOffset = 6;
    int bottomOffset = 6;
    UIEdgeInsets imageInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topOffset, 0, -bottomOffset, 0);

    [self.view addSubview:tabController.view];
}

// reset the background image in custom tabbar.
- (void) setTabBarBackground {

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnbg.png"]];
    img.frame = CGRectOffset(img.frame, 0, 1);
    img.frame = CGRectMake(img.frame.origin.x, img.frame.origin.y-1, img.frame.size.width, img.frame.size.height);
    [tabController.tabBar insertSubview:img atIndex:0];
    [img release];

}

// reset the background image in custom tabbar.
- (void) resetTabBar : (NSString *) tabid
{   
    [img1 removeFromSuperview];

    NSLog(@"tab id - %@",tabid);
    switch ([tabid intValue]) {
        case 0:
            img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-1.jpg"]];
            break;
        case 1:
            img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-2.jpg"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-3.jpg"]];
            break;
        case 3:
            img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-4.jpg"]];
            break;
        case 4:
            img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab-5.jpg"]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    img1.frame = CGRectOffset(img1.frame, 0, 1);
    [tabController.tabBar insertSubview:img1 atIndex:0];
    [tabController.tabBar bringSubviewToFront:img1];
    [img1 release];

}

// here push View controllers
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
}
```

Hope it gives you idea..

Comment: I have solved this problem is different way.Whatever thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Know it's already been answered, but wanted to offer an alternative approach.

Subclassing UITabBarController is a bad idea, according to the docs.  I also had no end of trouble when I actually tried to use a UIImagePickerController as one of the view controllers behind the subclassed tabbar.

I took a much simpler approach just overlaying a uibutton over the tabbar item.  Example project can be found here:

https://github.com/group6/RaisedCenterButton

It's just an example though.  You're still going to need to do the work to incorporate it into an app.

Answer (score 1):

This has been covered in quite a few tutorials. How most of these apps achieve the effect is they put a custom UIButton which follows similar styling to the Tab Bar on top of the tab bar in the center.

[iDev Recipes](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) has an excellent tutorial with the code example

Answer (score 0):

I would advise not to do this. iOS users are used to the familiar tab bar functionality. The highlight is sufficient to let them know on which tab they are.

Your design idea is very attractive, but it comes at a cost. The area above the bar beside the rased bar item is wasted, or the size of other icons have to be reduced. This will make it more difficult to use, not easier.

Here is a good tip: take 2 hours out of your busy life and read the Apple [Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556) for iOS from cover to cover. Its fascinating reading and will give you good guidance for design questions like this.

Comment: It's a give and take. I believe most app users will be impressed with a better and outstanding design rather then a more practical design approach.

Comment: Yes, that is also possible. Plus, user habits are changing constantly, and Apple can only exert so much control.

Comment: This does not add any value to the question. If it is a client's requires it we will ahve to develop it.

Comment: I disagree. Presumably, having read the most recent version of the HIG, you will be well positioned to educate your client about feasible user interface design. Indeed, being a quality programmer, this would be your duty.

Comment: I disagree. Custom tab bars are commonly used in top apps.